# Why Mishnah doesn't mention Halochos of Mishloach Manot, Matanot laEvionim and the Seudah?

Tags: halacha-theory, purim, mishna

Following my previous question on the origin of Purim Halochos, I wondered why the Mishnah doesn't mention Halochos of Mishloach Manot,  Matanot laEvionim, and the Seudah and only mentions a lot of Halachot of reading the Megillah?

Comment: It mentions Matanot laEvionim in Megillah 1:3 and 1:4.

Comment: There’s a lot of halachos that aren’t discussed in Mishnayos. Chanukah is almost never mentioned, for instance. Same for Tzitzis and Tefillin. Why would you think this should be included?

Comment: @DonielF התרחק מן הכיעור - if the Mitzvos are compared to organs, the Mishna seems very ill-formed so to speak. I would love hearing logical explanations of why certain Mitzvos are important enough to be included in the main compendium and why others aren't.

Comment: Are you going to remove Mattanot Laevyonim from the question already or not? What are you waiting for?

Comment: @DoubleAA That's not the point "they are mentioned", that's why I edited to "Halochos". They are mentioned but not as Halochos, Compare to Halochos of Megilah.